React Antd Table: FilteredValue
I tried to create a searchbar and a filterType on an Antd Table but the 2 Filters don't want to work together.
Here is my sandbox
My problem is when I uncomment filteredValue, my setFilteredType(value)    does not work anymore
Thanks in advance

I think the solution to this problem is to filter the dada source directly.

Thank you for your response but when I click on your sandbox, it displays "devbox not found"

wait a minute，i forgot to set public.

Hello, welcome to the site. Please spend some time to take the site [tour] and review the Help/How to Ask sections for tips to improve the quality of your post. The post should include more complete details about a specific issue, and if necessary, a complete [mcve] of the relevant code you are working with.

this is a solution codesandbox,
but i think the search action can filter data from the data source directly, don't need to filter by column's onFilterChange action.
